# Worklight : JSONStore and Angular rootScope synchronization

Tags: angularjs-scope, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic-framework, observable, jsonstore

I'm currently using Worklight 6.2 to develop an hybrid application for iOS, Android and Windows 8 thanks to Ionic Framework (based on AngularJS).
I developed most of my app without any problem for now, but today I started thinking about using JSONStore to persist and secure my local data (my application can be used offline).

So before now, I used scopes and the root scope of Angular to update my DOM thanks to data binding, as we always do with Angular. For example, I create a new item with the HMI, and thanks to data binding, my objects are immediately displayed in my app without having to reload anything, and my Javascript objects are updated with the latests values.

Now that I want to plug JSONStore, I'm facing the following issue : what is the most consistent and reliable way for my app to have my JSONStore synchronized with my root scope so that every time I get new updates in my scope, JSONStore is also updated and thus, data is saved and secured on the device (and ready to be synchronized with my backend).

My absolute reference must be JSONStore as it is my official reliable solution for persistent data storage (and encryption). The best thing would be for my app to use my JSONStore collection "as the root scope", but as far as I know, it's not possible to do this with Angular (actually, I did not check, as it sounds very wrong).
I ended up thinking that I need to maintain the 2 collections : my JSONStore and my root scope. Meaning that every time something is modified in the root scope, I have to apply it to the JSONStore. In order to facilitate maintainability, I think about observing my root scope's main object using the $watch listener, so that every time my root scope is modified, I crush my JSONStore with the latest value of my root scope. Something like this :

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    // Object to be watched
    return $rootScope.myObject;
}, function(newValue, oldValue){
    // Here, destroy the collection and init it again with the newValue object
});
```

I'm a little concerned about performances of watching this object during the whole lifecycle of my application. Even if the object will not be modified very often, the object can be "quite" big (50kb). Also, I'm not sure JSONStore really enjoys having its collections crushed every time. But not using this would mean identifying the "modification spots" to update JSONStore every time a modification is done to my root scope. This could work, but is really not optimal as we need to get used to duplicate source code (1 for the scope, 1 for the JSONStore).

Well, this is bothering me because I can't find a really viable solution, so if you guys have ideas / best practices about this, don't hesitate to share !

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context as to what you are trying to accomplish using updating JSONStore as frequently as you have described?

Comment: As explained, it will not really be frequently updated, it's just that it can be updated from a lot of different pages and controllers. If you want a concrete use case : I call my adapter on launch of the app, display the items in a list. I can "check" each item to validate them by clicking on a button. Once checked, the model and views are updated, but I need to then update my JSONStore to be synchronized with what I have in my scope. That's what I'd like to automate somehow, because I then need to synchronize my JSONStore collection with my adapter to save my data on the remote server.

Comment: You might have already tried this but perhaps you can save instances of JSONStore in your scope and watch for those changes in the data. The update those changes when they are triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to synchronise your scope to the JSONStore in the "background" and pull the data out when you need to for ex: on app start.

Watching JSONStore would require you to query the JSONStorage in the watch function which would be slow and wasteful.

As @cnandreu suggested you can interface with the JSONStorage via an angularjs service.

Here is a simple implementation with background synchronisation, [taken from this article](https://medium.com/@papasimons/worklight-angularjs-todo-app-a6f4e11bb6c3)

*|| note that the below code syncs the whole object, whereas if your object gets bigger I suggest to do some add/update and remove items functions in the service.||*

In your controller:

```
// get the object
todoJsonStorage.get().then(function(res) {
    $scope.todos = res;
});

// synchronise in the background
$scope.$watch('todos', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) { // This prevents unneeded calls to the local storage
            todoJsonStorage.put(todos);
        }
    }, true);
```

Your service is something like this:

```
/**
 * Services that persists and retrieves TODOs from Worklight JSON Storage
 */
angular.module('todomvc')
    .factory('todoJsonStorage', function ($q) {
        'use strict';

        var COLLECTION_NAME = 'todos';

        var collections = {
            todos: {
                searchFields: {title:'string', completed:'boolean'}
            }
        };

        var inited = false;

        //checks if inited and if not inits
        function initJSONStore(){
            var initDeferred = $q.defer();
            if (inited){
                initDeferred.resolve();
            } else {
                //Initialize the collection
                WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function () {
                    console.log("-> JSONStore init successful");
                    initDeferred.resolve();
                }).fail(function (errorObject) {
                    console.log("-> JSONStore error: " + errorObject.msg);
                });

                return initDeferred.promise;
            };
        }

        return {
            get: function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                initJSONStore().then(function(){
                    WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME).findAll().then(function (res) {
                        if (res.length > 0){
                            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(res[0].json.data || '[]'));
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve(res);
                        }

                    }).fail(function (errorObject) {
                        console.log("JSONStore findbyid error: " + errorObject.msg);
                    });
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },

            put: function (todos) {
                WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME).clear()
                WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME).add({data:JSON.stringify(todos)});
            }
        };

    });
```

Comment: Nice complement to Carlos' answer Gideon, thanks for the pointers. I'll definitely spot this as my alternate solution if I can't find any efficient way to sync my JSONStore with my scope (the other way is not necessary)

Comment: No worries, sync is a two way thing :) .. as this is a service you can also do the same background sync while the main object maintained is a service variable which then all the other controllers can bind to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar enough with Angular.js to answer your question.

However, for what it's worth this is what I would do:

- Make an Angular.js [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) that handles all JSONStore operations.
- Use dependency injection to get access to the service inside your controller(s).
- Follow the docs for [working with external data](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html?locale=en).

I wouldn't expect that service to be much different conceptually than working with a REST API.

A high level example would be something like a sign up page with user, email, first name, last name and other text fields. You would wait until all the fields are valid before saving a new person document with those fields inside your people collection.

Your view.html file will define the text fields and probably a save button (e.g. `ng-click=save()`). Your controller will have a `save()` function that will call the jsonstore service to save a new person document. When you need to populate data, you would  call something like this in your controller: `myJSONStoreService.getPerson('carlos', successCallback)` which will execute `WL.JSONStore.get('people').find({name: 'carlos'}).then(successCallback)` and return results in the `successCallback`.

There's no [data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) in the scenario I describe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Carlos. What you're describing is actually easy to set up and is a good way to store data in JSONStore, but I'd really like to check if it's possible to get an auto sync between my scope and my JSONStore, to avoid having to explicitly say "now, save to JSONStore" on top of the current controller I have. If for any reason, the developers forget to add instructions to add to the JSONStore, data will be shown in the UI (because available in the scope) but not in the persistent data layer. Maybe I'm going too far, but I'd like to see were I can go to automate this stuff.